# Multiple airport autocomplete airport inputs on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code example im currently working on. (i needed an exmaple of an autocomplete input for only airports) this is forked from someone on codepen, so credit on their behalf.

What it currently does?
The code curently autocompletes the airport code based on the city you input into the field. This is the expected behaviour and is fine.

What i am currently trying to achieve ?
I am now trying to add a second input (id name of autocomplete2) field to behave the exact same. So i can simple add 2 seperate airports, 1 in each input.

I have tried adding adding the following `var bc = $('#autocomplete2')` and using `var bc` thorugh the code but i am getting lost when it comes to the bottom of the code

```
function search(e) {
  if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 40) {
  return;
}

if (ac.val().length > 0) {
  results = _.take(fuse.search(ac.val()), 7);
  numResults = results.length;

  var divs = results.map(function(r, i) {
    return '<div class="autocomplete-result" data-index="'+ i +'">'
       + '<div><b>'+ r.iata +'</b> - '+ r.name +'</div>'
       + '<div class="autocomplete-location">'+ r.city +', '+ r.country +'</div>'
         + '</div>';
   });

  selectedIndex = -1;
  list.html(divs.join(''))
  .attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);

} else {
    numResults = 0;
    list.empty();
  }
}
```

I have reverted my changes and gone back to a single input for the time being.

`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrvgKQ?editors=0010`

EDIT

```
https://codepen.io/eyecandy91/pen/JZwrqy?editors=0010
```

Changing to a class allows me to use multiple inputs but now theres a issues with the dropdown when there is double inputs & double inputs on each class. Codepend updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this pen, I believe it should be working the way you want it: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrvZmv?editors=0011

```
var options = {
    shouldSort: true,
    threshold: 0.4,
    maxPatternLength: 32,
    keys: [{
      name: 'iata',
      weight: 0.5
    },
    {
      name: 'name',
      weight: 0.3
    },
    {
      name: 'city',
      weight: 0.2
    }]
};

var fuse = new Fuse(airports, options);

$('.autocomplete').each(function() {
    var ac = $(this);

    ac.on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    })
    .on('focus keyup', search)
    .on('keydown', onKeyDown);

    var wrap = $('<div>')
        .addClass('autocomplete-wrapper')
        .insertBefore(ac)
        .append(ac);

    var list = $('<div>')
        .addClass('autocomplete-results')
        .on('click', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            selectIndex($(this).data('index'), ac);
        })
        .appendTo(wrap);
});

$(document)
.on('mouseover', '.autocomplete-result', function(e) {
    var index = parseInt($(this).data('index'), 10);
    if (!isNaN(index)) {
        $(this).attr('data-highlight', index);
    }
})
.on('click', clearResults);

function clearResults() {
    results = [];
    numResults = 0;
    $('.autocomplete-results').empty();
}

function selectIndex(index, autoinput) {
    if (results.length >= index + 1) {
    autoinput.val(results[index].iata);
    clearResults();
    }  
}

var results = [];
var numResults = 0;
var selectedIndex = -1;

function search(e) {
    if (e.which === 38 || e.which === 13 || e.which === 40) {
        return;
    }
    var ac = $(e.target);
    var list = ac.next();
    if (ac.val().length > 0) {
        results = _.take(fuse.search(ac.val()), 7);
        numResults = results.length;

        var divs = results.map(function(r, i) {
            return '<div class="autocomplete-result" data-index="'+ i +'">'
                + '<div><b>'+ r.iata +'</b> - '+ r.name +'</div>'
                + '<div class="autocomplete-location">'+ r.city +', '+ r.country +'</div>'
                + '</div>';
        });

        selectedIndex = -1;
        list.html(divs.join(''))
            .attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);

    } else {
        numResults = 0;
        list.empty();
    }
}

function onKeyDown(e) {
    var ac = $(e.currentTarget);
    var list = ac.next();
    switch(e.which) {
        case 38: // up
            selectedIndex--;
            if (selectedIndex <= -1) {
                selectedIndex = -1;
            }
            list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
        break;
        case 13: // enter
            selectIndex(selectedIndex, ac);
        break;
        case 9: // enter
            selectIndex(selectedIndex, ac);
            e.stopPropagation();
        return;
        case 40: // down
            selectedIndex++;
            if (selectedIndex >= numResults) {
                selectedIndex = numResults-1;
            }
            list.attr('data-highlight', selectedIndex);
        break;

        default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action (scroll / move caret)
}
```

I put the autocomplete inputs through a loop to create the "dropdown"-container for each one and then changed most of the functions so that they would work for multiple inputs.

There's probably room for improvement and cleaning up, but hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

**Edit:** Found and fixed bug in `onKeyDown`-function

Comment: This is exactly what was specified and the desired outcome is 100% what im looking for. I totaly looked beyond using $(this); excellent. Upvoted and answered

Comment: Hi Nikola, I'm trying to append both iata and name into input value, but it's not working. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Just tried below code and it's working fine. Can you validate it's correct or not?
autoinput.val(results[index].iata + " - " + results[index].name);

Comment: Hi @Sandy Yes, that's the way I would have solved it aswell! With newer syntax you could write: ``autoinput.val(`${results[index].iata} - ${results[index].name}`)``